# Proper Connector for ADC

Tags: analog, adc, connector, input

I am designing a PCB including several ADC chips. For the analog input, I need to choose a proper connector. Someone recommended to use a BNC connector, but it seems to be too huge. Do you have other recommendations? EG, can I use a simple male/female connector, like in the image? And, after all, does it matter in the overall design?
Thanks
[image]

Comment: What analog signals are you measuring? Are they particular fast or high-impedance?

Comment: Its max frequency is 20kHz, sorry forgot to mention

Comment: At 20 kHz, assuming no other extreme specifications like high impedance, or high humidity, or thermocouple levels of accuracy, you should get away with it. Spend a little extra on gold plated for both male and female parts if thermal emfs might be a problem.

Comment: A proper connector to what? Please be specific. Used by the end user? Or interior connector used only by a technician? How many circuits?